# ifelse() vs attach() to create new column of data frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a new column in a data frame that will be used as part of a model (using the `tree()` function).

When defining the new column using `ifelse()`, R returns a warning that NAs were introduced by coercion.

```
library(ISLR)
library(tree)

Carseats$High <- ifelse(Carseats$Sales <= 8, "No", "Yes")

> tree.carseats <- tree(High~.-Sales, data = Carseats)
Warning message:
In tree(High ~ . - Sales, data = Carseats) : NAs introduced by coercion
> summary(tree.carseats)
Error in y - frame$yval[object$where] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Meanwhile, the following code using `attach()` seems to work properly. No NAs are introduced by coercion, and `tree()` works as intended.

```
library(ISLR)
library(tree)

attach(Carseats)
High <- ifelse(Sales <= 8, "No", "Yes")
Carseats <- data.frame(Carseats, High)

> tree.carseats <- tree(High~.-Sales, data = Carseats)
> summary(tree.carseats)

Classification tree:
tree(formula = High ~ . - Sales, data = Carseats)
Variables actually used in tree construction:
[1] "ShelveLoc"   "Price"       "Income"      "CompPrice"   "Population" 
[6] "Advertising" "Age"         "US"         
Number of terminal nodes:  27 
Residual mean deviance:  0.4575 = 170.7 / 373 
Misclassification error rate: 0.09 = 36 / 400
```

There does not appear to be any difference in the two versions of the `High` column in `Carseats` before feeding the data into the `tree()` function.

Could someone please help me understand why I am getting two different results? Is there a way to get this to work using base `ifelse()` (or without `attach()`)?

Comment: always: **without** `attach()` **!** See `library("fortunes"); fortune(379)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data.frame()` function has the option `stringsAsFactors` which defaults to `stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors()`. The default value of `default.stringsAsFactors()` is `TRUE`, therefore your call to `data.frame()` creates `High` as a `factor`, whereas `ifelse()` creates a `character` by default.

Just use

```
Carseats$High <- factor(ifelse(Carseats$Sales <= 8, "No", "Yes"))
```

to get it to work without attaching the data.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tree)
library(tidyverse)
data(Carseats, package = "ISLR")
Carseats %>%
    mutate(High = as.factor(Sales <= 8)) -> Carseats

tree(High ~ . - Sales, data = Carseats) -> tsmry
summary(tsmry)
```

- No need to load `ISLR` if you only need data from that package. `data` function delivers that
- `TRUE` / `FALSE` are better flags than `Yes` / `No` think of any potential future control flow. For boolean variable you can do `if (bool_var)` instead of `if (my_flag == "yes")`

  - You can then drop `ifelse` function